# MySql query challenge - return results with whitespace?

Tags: php, mysql, database, select

I have a MySql database with some rows as follows:

```
ID    DESC
 1    This is my bike
 2    Motorbikes are great
 3    All bikers should wear helmets
 4    A bike is great for exercise
 5    A. Top. Bike.
```

What I want to do is return the rows with whitespace surrounding the search term, OR the term being at the end or beginning of the description.

For example,

```
"SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE `desc` LIKE '%bike%'"
```

Will return all rows. But,

```
"SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE `desc` LIKE '% bike %'
```

Will only return row 4.

What I really want is a reliable way to return rows 1, 4 and 5, i.e. where the search term is sorrounded with anything BUT chars A-z, 0-9. Any ideas? Is this even possible with MySql?

Thanks!!

Comment: you can use mysql regex

Comment: Regex in Mysql Query. Refer [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html)

Comment: And the answer is...

SELECT * FROM reviews WHERE description REGEXP '[[:<:]]desc[[:>:]]'

Fast and efficient. Thanks StackOverflow!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should start reading about [**MySql RegEx**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html).

Sample Code.

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE field_name REGEXP PATTERN;`

**More Specific**

**details Table**

```
ID      NAME
1       Dipesh
2       Dip
3       Dipe
4       DiDi
5       Di
```

```
SELECT * FROM details WHERE NAME REGEXP '^Di$';
```

**Result**

NAME -> Di

```
SELECT * FROM details WHERE NAME REGEXP 'Di$';
```

**Result**

NAME -> DiDi , Di

```
SELECT * FROM details WHERE NAME REGEXP '^Di';
```

**Result**

NAME -> Dip, DiDi, Di

Comment: Thanks - Regex is the way to go.

Comment: From here: http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/484/use-regular-expressions-in-mysql-select-statements/

    SELECT * FROM `desc` WHERE description REGEXP '[[:<:]]bike[[:>:]]'

Works well and returns results in 0.0075 seconds on my WAMP server with 25k+ rows

Answer (score 3):

You can use regular expressions in SQL

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE desc REGEXP '\bbike\b'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the additional conditions in the query:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    `mytable`
WHERE
    `desc` LIKE '% bike %' OR
    `desc` LIKE '% bike' OR
    `desc` LIKE 'bike %';
```

Comment: LIKE is case-sensitive: force case comparison to ensure that row 5 is returned as well

Comment: @MarkBaker Interesting. According to [MySQL Docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/case-sensitivity.html) `LIKE` is case-insensitive.

Comment: Depends on collation; but you most recommendations these days are to use utf-8, which is case-sensitive

Comment: Agree, but default one isn't and in a lot of installations that's the case.

Comment: I think UTF8_collation is case insensitive, but UFT8_bin is sensitive according to my tests.

One thing though - `desc` LIKE 'bike %' will still match 'motorbike', for example.

Comment: Sorry - I meant UTF8_unicode_ci is case-insensitive above.

I like this solution for its readability so +1 for that! But it still doesn't work for all cases

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, hope it'll help you

```
"SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE `desc` LIKE '% bike'
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).